# jQuery Tabs: toggling links from outside the tab group

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using jquery Tabs to create my tabs. I have the following html code:

```
<div class='product-children-menu'>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='#12345'>Stuff link</a></li>
      <li><a href='#67890'>More Stuff Link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class='children'>
  <div id='12345'>Stuff here</div>
  <div id='67890'>More Stuff</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to use a separate link on the page (preferably, an a tag wrapping an image) so that when I click on the image, it would toggle and show the appropriate tab. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) setter like so:

```
$('.myLink').click(function(e) {
    $( ".myTabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 ); // 1 is tab index
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the active tab based on something other than the index? For example, if the order of the tabs changed (which may be possible in my case), the index would change and the link would open up the wrong tab.

Comment: Yes just find the index of the tab based on whatever criteria you need. The `1` in the example could be a variable that is an integer found earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a different way of doing this as well:

```
$('.activate-children-menu-tab').click(function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var children = $('ul#product-children-menu').find('li a');
    children.each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
        if($this.attr('href') === href) {
           $this.trigger('click');
       }
    });
});
```

When a link which has the activate-children-menu-tab class is clicked, it triggers the appropriate tag link.